# What are the Docusign rate limits for OAuth calls?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm considering using **https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo** endpoint to verify if the user's access token is valid before calling eSignature API.

However, I have not been able to find any information regarding the rate limits for OAuth calls, only for specific DocuSign APIs.

Are there any **rate limits for OAuth calls**, specifically for get userInfo, and if so what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit, but your workflow wouldn't really be recommended as that endpoint is not meant to be used for the purposes of token validation. Couldn't you just call eSig and use retry logic (i.e getting a new token) if you get an unauthorised response? Have a look at our [quick start](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/overview/) applications for ideas on how to do this.